# Any class/structure to store a pair of dates in .NET 2.0 libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Is there a class or structure in standard .NET 2.0 libraries which would hold two `DateTime` objects - date from and date to? Basically an improved `TimeSpan`. I can write my own structure without a problem but why do it if someone had already done it before?

Things to note:

- `TimeSpan` alone doesn't cut it as it holds a time interval, not two dates.
- `Tuple` is out of question as it's not available in .NET 2.0
- `KeyValuePair` is something I'd rather avoid as there's no distinguishable key or value, it's just two dates.
- `DateTime[]` is an alternative, yes, but I'm asking about structure/class because if it exists, it might have some other useful things coming along with it.

So, any neat solution I'm missing or should I just write it myself and/or stop being so picky?

Comment: Asking for recommendation is off-topic on SO, but I suggest you to look at [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) from John Skeet

Comment: @Steve Why is asking about standard .NET libraries asking for recommendation?

Comment: There isn't. Just create your own type.

Comment: Well it is a thin line here, but I should admit that I haven't read carefully your question.

Comment: I use Jon Skeet's `Range` class from his `MiscUtils` class. Should be easy to find in a search. It's old now and maybe superceded by NodaTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Pair` class

Visual Basic:

```
Dim value As Pair(Of String, String) = new Pair(Of String, String) With (foo, bar)
```

C#:

```
Pair<String, String> value = new Pair<String, String>(foo, bar);
```

Untested and there might be typos, it has passed a fair amount of time since I have worked either in Visual Basic or C#.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.Pair%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: String parsing is slow and you dont need string versions of tick values in long form.

Answer (score 0):

How about a Tuple or a variation with two date times and and additional double offset.

Comment: Obviously writing your own class or structure would be very easy, but back then I was only intereseted in something already defined in .NET libraries. Tuples don't exist in .NET 2.0.